# select rows that match condition in several columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataset with more than 2 million lines and several columns. Some columns are hospital codes, which correspond to all the conditions each patient had during that hospitalisation. I need to perform some summaries for each condition, so I'm trying to create a dataset that will have information about a singular condition of interest.

The codes have 5 digits, but sometimes I want to select codes that begin with three digits (the remaining two digits don't mattter), for instance I want every row that has a code that begin with 401 in all the columns that contains these codes. Small example:

```
id dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_n
1  401  
2  2500 4011
3  18524
```

I would want id 1 and 2. I've tried something but I get an error and it's slow. Any pointers or suggestions are most welcomed. If anything is unclear I will try to give more information.

```
final_DB[apply(grep(paste("^", i, sep=""), final_DB[,10:29]), 1, any),]
```

`i` correspond to the number I want so in this case `i <- 401` and the columns 10 to 29 are all the columns where this code might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be `filter_at` to select the columns of interest, check whether any of the variables have the `substr`, 401 at the beginning to filter the rows

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter_at(vars(starts_with("dx")), any_vars(substr(., 1, 3) == '401'))
#    id dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_n
#1  1  401   NA   NA   NA
#2  2 2500 4011   NA   NA
```

---

Or using `base R`, loop through the columns of interest (in this case, all the columns except the first), use `grepl` and check if the `pattern` "^401" is there or not - returns a `list` of logical `vector`s, which we `Reduce` to a single logical `vector` with `|`, use that to subset the rows of the data

```
df1[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[-1], grepl, pattern = "^401")), ]
```

---

Regarding the issue in the OP's post

```
final_DB[apply(grep(paste("^", i, sep=""), final_DB[,10:29]), 1, any),]
```

Here the `grep` is applied on a data.frame instead of a `vector` and `grep` works on `vector/matrices`.  To correct it we loop through the rows (it would be inefficient though - just to correct the code)

```
i1 <- apply(final_DB[, 10:29], 1, function(x) any(grepl(paste("^", i, sep=""), x)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, dx_1 = c(401L, 2500L, 18524L), dx_2 = c(NA, 
 4011L, NA), dx_3 = c(NA, NA, NA), dx_n = c(NA, NA, NA)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I especially like the use of `filter_at`, since I'm starting to use the `tidyverse` library.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use `mtcars` to demonstrate one method (in base R). (BTW: it is not clear to me that your data is `character` or `numeric`, but it doesn't matter: `grep*` functions will happily convert to `character` to find things, as in `grepl("^123", 122:124)` ... though floating point regex should obviously be taken with a [grain-of-salt](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).)

Let's say we want every row where something starts with 20 through 25:

```r
mt <- mtcars[1:10, 1:7]
sapply(mt, grepl, pattern = "^2[0-5]")
#         mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec
#  [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#  [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [8,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#  [9,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

To highlight what those are:

```
mt
#                    mpg   cyl    disp    hp   drat      wt    qsec
# Mazda RX4        *21.0*    6   160.0   110   3.90   2.620   16.46
# Mazda RX4 Wag    *21.0*    6   160.0   110   3.90   2.875   17.02
# Datsun 710       *22.8*    4   108.0    93   3.85   2.320   18.61
# Hornet 4 Drive   *21.4*    6  *258.0*  110   3.08   3.215   19.44
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7     8   360.0   175   3.15   3.440   17.02
# Valiant           18.1     6  *225.0*  105   2.76   3.460  *20.22*
# Duster 360        14.3     8   360.0  *245*  3.21   3.570   15.84
# Merc 240D        *24.4*    4   146.7    62   3.69   3.190  *20.00*
# Merc 230         *22.8*    4   140.8    95   3.92   3.150  *22.90*
# Merc 280          19.2     6   167.6   123   3.92   3.440   18.30
```

Now to use this:

```r
mt[ rowSums(sapply(mt, grepl, pattern = "^2[0-5]")) > 0, ]
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02
# Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44
# Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22
# Duster 360     14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00
# Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90
```

If you only need to check a specific set of columns, add the column-selection to `mt` within the `sapply`:

```r
mt[ rowSums(sapply(mt[,c(1,4,7)], grepl, pattern = "^2[0-5]")) > 0, ]
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02
# Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44
# Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22
# Duster 360     14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00
# Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90
```